# What is best for SEO own site or redirect to existing site with that product?

Tags: seo, domains

I helped someone with a shopify shop which sells products for securing items e.g. clamps, tie boss, shockstrap. The site is called quickfistclamps.co.uk. We currently have a page for these individual products. We also bought shockstrap.co.uk and tieboss.co.uk which both redirect to the individual product pages on the quickfistclamps.co.uk site.

What I was wondering is how beneficial would it be to create a separate site to advertise these products under there specific domain names (shockstrap.co.uk and tieboss.co.uk) and then show them they can purchase them through the other site (quickfistclamps) compared with the current redirect?

Comment: Nowadays, trying to take SEO advantage with keywords in URLs is old-fashioned and useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google no longer gives preferential treatment to exact match domains so the SEO benefit from this is essentially zero. Furthermore, you may find your users will experience trust issues if they see the product on one website and then are taken to another to complete their purchase.

Your best bet is to use the domains for marketing purposes and usability (they're shorter then the full URL to the product on the main site). But I wouldn't use them to host separate content from the main site.